# Zend Framework Zend_Gdata google apps api changes

Tags: gmail, zend-gdata

We got this notice about API changes:

http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.com/2014/09/deprecated-google-apps-admin-apis-to-be.html

How does this affect Zend_Gdata?  I see the return is now JSON markup language.

I am running ZendGdata 1.11.11 and I admit I am not a php/zend programmer but we need a few basic interactions with gmail to continue to work (verify user and password handling).  If the underlying framework works like it does now, I should be okay?  Are there changes (upgrades) to Zend_Gdata that I need to done?

thanks for your time
-et

Update: Instead of Zend, are we to use this code?:

https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

Answer (score 0):

I've seen others do the same.  I guess the github is the way to go, it requires several actions for OAUTH2 support.  Zend should probably post a message that it is going to break on April 2015, unless they plan on supporting the new api calls in some fashion.